# ASP.NET Web Application template has no login and register in nav bar

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, templates, visual-studio-2017

I choose a new project as asp .net web application (MVC) in Visual Studio 2017, but it has no login and register in top right of navigation bar!
That is my problem?

Comment: do you want default asp.net login authentication in your project??

Comment: yes I do. I mean exactly this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you create a new project visual studio has a button called: Change Authentication, clicking there you have a few options:

- No Authentication
- Individual User Accounts
- Work or School Accounts
- Windows Authentication

Choose **Individual User Accounts** and you should see the options in the navbar.

ps: if you chose an Empty template project this button is not available. You need to choose any other option.

Comment: Tnx a lot, Can I fix this after start the project?

Comment: You need to change manually. Maybe the easiest way is creating another project and see the differences between them.

Comment: Tnx very much!!